# How to Synchronize data on Cloud?

Tags: android, synchronization, cloud

> I am novice on cloud and i need to synchronize my data(Contact,image,video)
>   on cloud. But i don't have any code or idea. i have some knowledge about the cloud
>   computing but but i don't know how it implement in android.
>   Pls provide me some code or tutorial.
>   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code depends on what service you want to use. If you are not sure what provider you want to use I suggest you try a cloud-client that supports multiple providers like [jclouds](http://www.jclouds.org).

The [quick start](http://www.jclouds.org/documentation/) guides should get you going quickly.

Comment: I need to synchronize my phone data on cloud.If i sync my contact and suppose i lose my mobile, then i able to backup this data on my mobile.I heard about mobster, is it helpful for me?

Comment: @sandiparmal Sorry, I'm not familiar with mobster. Next time you ask a question you should include your use case in the question, that way you get better answers :) Good luck!